# C scanf format string warning

Tags: c, scanf, format-string

I'm working on Euler #3 (http://projecteuler.net/problem=3). I think I've got the logic right, but I'm getting an error when trying to use scanf (and printf) with a long. I'm current trying to use %li and this is the error I'm getting:

```
euler3.c: In function ‘main’:
euler3.c:30: warning: format ‘%li’ expects type ‘long int **’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’
euler3.c:30: warning: format ‘%li’ expects type ‘long int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’
```

I understand the error, but for the life of me I can't find the solution. Here's my code if it's needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

long greatestPrime(long num)
{
        int i;

        for(i = 2; i <= num; i++)
        {
                if(num%i == 0)
                {
                        num = num/i;
                        i--;
                }
        }

        return num;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        unsigned long greatest;

        printf("Enter number to find prime factor: ");
        scanf("%li",greatest);

        printf("%li",greatestPrime(greatest));

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`scanf` is looking for a pointer to a long integer (`long int *`), not a long integer, so you need to pass the address of `greatest` by using the `&` operator:

```
scanf("%li", &greatest);
```

As another answer shows as well, you need to use `%lu`, as you're using an `unsigned long int`:

```
scanf("%lu", &greatest);
```

Comment: Not correct. Using `scanf` with an improper format specifier results in Undefiend Behavior. `printf` and `scanf` are not format safe.User needs to take care of it, in this case it should be `lu`

Comment: Using %li got rid of errors and gave me the correct answer. I do understand why %lu is correct though. Thanks!

Comment: Given that greatestPrime takes a signed long you may be better of changing the type of greatest to just be `long int`, however, since you're finding primes unsigned would give you a greater range of values you can test on.

Answer (score 3):

Use `%lu` format, as it represents an `unsigned long int` instead of just a `long int`

```
scanf("%lu",&greatest);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for `scanf` to modify your variable, it needs the address of it (a pointer to your variable). Pass the address of `greatest` using the `&` operator:

```
scanf("%lu", &greatest);
```

**EDIT**: Also, `%li` should be `%lu`, since `greatest` is unsigned.

Comment: Not correct. Using `scanf` with an improper format specifier results in Undefiend Behavior. `printf` and `scanf` are not format safe.User needs to take care of it, in this case it should be `lu`

Answer (score 1):

You're passing an integer to `scanf()`:

```
scanf("%li",greatest);
```

You should be passing the address of a variable properly typed to hold an **unsigned** long integer:

```
scanf("%lu", &greatest);
```

Comment: Not correct. Using `scanf` with an improper format specifier results in Undefiend Behavior. `printf` and `scanf` are not format safe.User needs to take care of it, in this case it should be `lu`

Comment: Als: Ha! I was so busy noticing the missing `&` I overlooked the `unsigned`. Thanks!